# Reset timepicker to default initialisation value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I use bootstrap-timepicker ( https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/ ) for a calendar. When you initialize the library with:

```
        $('.timepicker-input-start').timepicker({
            showInputs: false
        });
```

the input will get the closest :15 , :30, :45 , :00 minute. The problem is sometimes I change this value and I need to come back to the default. How can I achieve that?

For example in this moment the clock is: 10:31 PM so the input will be 10:45 PM on initialization.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - are you simply looking for the options `snapToStep` and `minuteStep` that can be found in the documentation you linked to?

Comment: This is what I was looking for: `$(".timepicker-input-start").val('').timepicker('setDefaultTime', 'current');`